# SQL Query Excluding value

Tags: sql

I've got a query in which I want to exclude a specific value (in this example "Mat")

The query works perfect without the sub-query in it:

```
SELECT test.SAME , test.Nationality, test.Name, coalesce(test2.Job,'')jobb
  FROM test
  LEFT JOIN test2
  ON test.noID=test2.noID
  WHERE test.SAME = 555 and test.Name NOT IN (
                                              SELECT *
                                              FROM test
                                              WHERE test.NAME = "Mat"
                                              )
  group by SAME , name
  order by same desc
```

Example here:

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f1fb/28

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f1fb/34

Comment: This is not working because you are comparing `test.Name` with `SELECT *`, if your subquery was `SELECT test.Name FROM` it works. Btw, as people suggested use directly `!=` or `<>` or `NOT LIKE` to exclude Name without subquery ;)

Comment: It is bad practice to nest select statements in your where clause. You should rather use joins and exclude based on matches in your where clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this, if you want to match exact name with **Mat**:

```
SELECT test.SAME , test.Nationality, test.Name, coalesce(test2.Job,'')jobb
  FROM test
  LEFT JOIN test2
  ON test.noID=test2.noID
  WHERE test.SAME = 555 and test.Name != "Mat"

group by SAME , name
  order by same desc
```

if you want to exclude all that contains **Mat** then:

```
SELECT test.SAME , test.Nationality, test.Name, coalesce(test2.Job,'')jobb
      FROM test
      LEFT JOIN test2
      ON test.noID=test2.noID
      WHERE test.SAME = 555 and test.Name NOT LIKE '%Mat%'

    group by SAME , name
      order by same desc
```

if you want to exclude that starts with **Mat** then:

```
SELECT test.SAME , test.Nationality, test.Name, coalesce(test2.Job,'')jobb
          FROM test
          LEFT JOIN test2
          ON test.noID=test2.noID
          WHERE test.SAME = 555 and test.Name NOT LIKE 'Mat%'

        group by SAME , name
          order by same desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `NOT LIKE` [statement](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp):

```
SELECT test.SAME , test.Nationality, test.Name, coalesce(test2.Job,'')jobb
  FROM test
  LEFT JOIN test2
  ON test.noID=test2.noID
  WHERE test.SAME = 555 and test.Name not like 'Mat'
  group by SAME , name
  order by same desc
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f1fb/33)

Or the `<>` or `!=` [operator](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp):

```
SELECT test.SAME , test.Nationality, test.Name, coalesce(test2.Job,'')jobb
  FROM test
  LEFT JOIN test2
  ON test.noID=test2.noID
  WHERE test.SAME = 555 and test.Name <> 'Mat'
  group by SAME , name
  order by same desc
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f1fb/37)

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be:--

```
SELECT test.SAME , test.Nationality, test.Name, coalesce(test2.Job,'')jobb
  FROM test
  LEFT JOIN test2
  ON test.noID=test2.noID
  WHERE test.SAME = 555 and test.Name NOT IN (
                                          SELECT NAME
                                          FROM test
                                          WHERE test.NAME = "Mat"
                                          )
  group by SAME , name
  order by same desc
```

Answer (score 0):

the sub query will not work because you have given select * in the sub query but in he outer query you have only a single column to match which is test.Name. If you would have put the sub query like (SELECT test.Name FROM test WHERE test.NAME = "Mat") then the whole query would have worked. but by the way there is no need of subquery itself here to get your desired result.